# Как пересчитать продолжительность в метаданных видео?

Tags: ffmpeg, видео, метаданные

После ускорения

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "setpts=PTS/4000" -r 120 0(4kx).mp4
```

видео длится доли секунды, но продолжительность в метаданных осталась несколько часов. Из-за чего тот же ffmpeg его некорректно отрабатывает. Как можно установить верную продолжительность в метаданных в большом количестве видео?